# Android: I18n with parameters

Tags: android, internationalization

I know there is support in Android for 18n an application, but can I give parameters to such a string? In Rails, I can do something like this:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello %{name}! You've got %{count} messages."

t("hello", name: "Klaus", count: 5)
```

Is there something similar in Android or do I have to do it myself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To elaborate on Heiko's answer, and to show your specific example, if you want to have more than one string you need to number them:

```
<string name="hello">Hello %1$s! You've got %2$d messages.</string>
```

This way you can switch the order of the strings in each translation. Using it would be:

```
String hello = getString(R.strings.hello, "Klaus", 5);
```

Comment: According documentation you need number only then you need reorder items: _Argument index. Normally, each format specifier consumes the next argument to format. For convenient localization, it's possible to reorder arguments so that they appear in a different order in the output than the order in which they were supplied. For example, "%4$s" formats the fourth argument (4$) as a string (s). It's also possible to reuse an argument with <. For example, format("%o %<d %<x", 64) results in "100 64 40"._

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same

In strings.xml you can put

```
<string name="xyz">Do you really want to report [%s] as spammer?</string>
```

and then in your code you put

```
String foo = getString(R.strings.xyz,"Joe Doe");
```

See [Context.getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 0):

[Phrase](https://github.com/square/phrase)  seems to do exactly what you're looking for. [Here's a article](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/android-string-formatting-with-phrase/) about it's implementation. Below sample from the article.

```
<string name="greeting"> Hello {name}, today\'s cook yielded {yield} {unit}.</string>
```

and then...

```
// Call put(...) in any order
CharSequence greeting = Phrase.from(context, R.string.greeting)
    .put("unit", unit)
    .put("name", name)
    .put("yield", yield)
    .format();
```